# mediaelement.js not playing MP3 in Opera

Tags: mp3, opera, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

Using the sample provided with mediaelement.js (mediaelementplayer-audio.html) I am unable to play MP3 files in Opera.  It works if I navigate Opera to http://www.mediaelementjs.com but if I try to hit the files from my localhost, it doesn't play.  The control renders correctly, but it doesn't appear to load.  I am running Opera 12.14 on Windows XP I have already tested Chrome 24, Firefox 18, IE8 (Flash fallback), and Safari 5.1.7 and only Opera is giving me an issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: this will not work on IIS 5.1, works on Apache or IIS 7.

Long answer:
After looking at the developer tools in Opera, I was able to find out that the MP3 was being partial received from the server.  Then I remembered that IIS 5.1 (which is the web server that I was using) doesn't properly support this.  I then compared the HTTP response header from www.mediaelementjs.com and it said that it was using Apache.  I read up online that range requests work under IIS 7.  So I moved my web app to a Windows 7 machine and sure enough, it worked.  I had to remember to explicitly define my MIME types, but everything is working now.